# Using JMeter to test an OpenXava application

Tags: jmeter, openxava

I'm facing a problem when writing a JMeter test plan.
The goal is to test an OpenXava based application.

I perform the request with firefox then I try to copy the headers, parameters and cookies in my HTTP request sampler (thus in JMeter).

There are a lot of parameters (36) sent when trying to login. I copied all of them.

However, I can't make it work.

The HTTP response seems useless. It's nearly the same I get when sending a wwrong password with Firefox :

```
throw 'allowScriptTagRemoting is false.';
//#DWR-INSERT
//#DWR-REPLY
var s0={};
dwr.engine._remoteHandleCallback('1','0',{application:"bdsa",changedParts:null,currentRow:-1,dialogLevel:0,dialogTitle:null,error:null,focusPropertyId:null,forwardInNewWindow:false,forwardURL:null,forwardURLs:null,hideDialog:false,module:"SignIn",nextModule:null,propertiesUsedInCalculations:null,reload:true,resizeDialog:false,selectedRows:null,showDialog:false,strokeActions:s0,urlParam:null,viewMember:"",viewSimple:false});
```

Do you have a clue about what is happening ? Should I try to test the login page with another method ?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just record your flow using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) and your browser.

1. [Set up JMeter Proxy Server](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf)
2. Set up your browser to use JMeter as the proxy
3. Perform the test scenario in the browser - JMeter should capture the requests under the [Recording Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Recording_Controller)
4. Perform [correlation](https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-handle-correlation-in-jmeter) if required. If your application is deployed in the Internet you might get benefit of cloud-based proxy service which can perform automated detection of dynamic parameters and generating the relevant code to extract the values and substitute recorded hard-coded parameters with the variables
5. Don't forget to add [HTTP Cookie Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) to your Test Plan - it deals with cookies and cookie-based authentication

Comment: It didn't work. I did what you suggest (the test recorder is great btw) but the authentication still don't work with JMeter...